# Include button into QComboBox or QCompleter

Tags: qt, user-interface, autocomplete, custom-controls, qcompleter

How to include a QPushButton into popup created by QCompleter?

I would use QFrame with a Listbox or QTableView and QPushButton included. But method void QCompleter::setPopup(QAbstractItemView *popup)  requires QAbstractItemView (not QWidget).

What is desired:

[image: QCompleter with QPushButton "Add color" included]

Answer (score 0):

I never used a `QCompleter`, but all visual items in Qt are derived from `QWidget`.
If you check the doc for QAbstractItemView you see it is derived from `QAbstractScrollArea` -> `QFrame` -> `QWidget`, so it is a `QWidget` after all, but you have to use specialized form. The `QAbstractItemView` has some child classes you can use, like `QListView` or `QColumnView`. Check the Qt doc for more info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qabstractitemview.html

Comment: How to create derived class from QlistView with a button?

Comment: How to create derived class from QListView with a button? And correct scrollbar (scrolling only list and not the button part? Do I have to override the paint method?